# server timeout on Dynamo DB query operation to get items from a table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have an array of ids (`eventids`) which can be million or billion ids inside the table. I am using a for loop to go through each id and retrieve an item from a dynamo db table using the query operation in PHP. However, because the query operation goes over a large amount of info in my table, it takes too long the query operation to do its work.  So, in this case I don't get any result because I get a time out. The following code tries to do this operation, which is failing for large amounts of info. I am wondering if you have any recommendation or suggestions on how to make the query operation faster and doable for large amounts of ids inside the `$sfweventarrayRDS` array?

```
    for ($j = 0 ; $j < count($sfweventarrayRDS) ; $j++){
        $keyconditions = array(
            "eventid" => array(
                "ComparisonOperator" => ComparisonOperator::EQ,
                "AttributeValueList" => array(
                    array(Type::NUMBER => $sfweventarrayRDS[$j]["eventid"])
                )
            )
        );

        $sfweventarrayDynamo = Dynamo::getItems("eventlocation",$keyconditions,$limit);

        if (count($sfweventarrayDynamo) > 0){

            $timediffepoch = $sfweventarrayDynamo[0]["edatecreated"]["N"] - $sfweventarrayRDS[$j]["edatecreated"];
            $timediffstandard = new DateTime("@$timediffepoch");

            if ($timediffstandard->format('i') >= 5){
                $starttimeepoch = $sfweventarrayRDS[$j]["edatecreated"];
                $endtimeepoch = $sfweventarrayDynamo[0]["edatecreated"]["N"];
                $starttimestandard = new DateTime("@$starttimeepoch");
                $endtimestandard = new DateTime("@$endtimeepoch");

                $each_event = array("eventid" => $sfweventarrayDynamo[0]["eventid"]["N"], 
                                    "organizationid" => $sfweventarrayRDS[$j]["organizationid"],
                                    "userid" => $sfweventarrayDynamo[0]["userid"]["N"],
                                    "starttime" => $starttimestandard->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 
                                    "endtime" => $endtimestandard->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                                    "location" => $sfweventarrayRDS[$j]["location"],
                                    "startlatitude" => $sfweventarrayRDS[$j]["latitude"],
                                    "startlongitude" => $sfweventarrayRDS[$j]["longitude"],
                                    "endlatitude" => $sfweventarrayDynamo[0]["latitude"]["N"],
                                    "endlongitude" => $sfweventarrayDynamo[0]["longitude"]["N"]);
                array_push($safewalkeventsDynamo, $each_event);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be two possible solutions that can improve your query operation:

1. Use batch get: If you already know event IDs and want to query the db to get more information, then batch get would be ideal. You create a chunk of 100 IDs (max allowed) and call DynamoDB to get information in one go. Repeat until you get all the IDs. [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_BatchGetItem_v20111205.html) is the documentation link.
2. You can increase your tables' read capacity according to your needs. (This will result in paying more money for dynamoDB.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I will definitely use it as a future reference. So, I figured out the problem wasn't the server timeout but rather the ajax call. Thus, instead of making it as webservice call I created a command line tool which could be run on the server and gives me the result although it takes sometime.